# nim re, regex modul is not filling match group

Tags: regex, nim-lang

I want to use the regex module of the nim library:

```
import re

var s="""<webSettings>
<add key="MyLaborPassword" value="shadowed" />
<add key="MyLaborUserID" value="shadowed" />
<add key="MyLaborUrl" value="shadowed" />
<add key="DebugSoapLoggingEnabled" value="false" />
  </webSettings>
 """


var matches : seq[string] = @[]

echo s.find(re"""MyLaborP(ass)word""",matches)
echo matches
```

Gives me

```
25
@[]
```

but i except:

```
25
@["ass"]
```

what have i missed?

Comment: `re.find` fills in the sequence (or array), it doesn't add to it; if it's an empty sequence it will remain empty. Use `var matches = newSeq[string](1)` instead (i.e. a 1-element seq) or make it an `array[1, string]`.

Comment: Reimer Behrends, this worked! But its a little strange behavior in my opinion.

Comment: Davidos Krausos, this is because `find()` takes an `openarray[string]` parameter to accommodate both seqs and arrays, but an `openarray` parameter is not resizable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [re](http://nim-lang.org/docs/re.html) module is deprecated and has been a bit buggy in my experience. You can use the new nre module:

```
import nre, options

var s="""<webSettings>
<add key="MyLaborPassword" value="shadowed" />
<add key="MyLaborUserID" value="shadowed" />
<add key="MyLaborUrl" value="shadowed" />
<add key="DebugSoapLoggingEnabled" value="false" />
  </webSettings>
 """


echo s.find(re"""MyLaborP(ass)word""").get.captures[0]
```

Which prints `ass`.

Comment: i've also tried nre before, but i've missed the `options`...
I had to install `options` with nimble as well. And i had to clear the nimcache before compiling.

Comment: You might be on an old version of Nim. The current Nim 0.12.0 comes with the options module. Nimcache clearing is a bug that I hoped would be fixed by now.